# How to Autoplay an HTML5 video on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, video

I'm working on a fairly simple mobile App, geared more towards people who may have trouble with technology. As such, it needs to be as easy to use as possible and I need to be able to play HTML5 audio/video files on start. The problem, as many of you may know, is that mobile devices tend to turn off Autoplay of video content for bandwidth purposes. I'm told there are ways around it using some mild scripting, but all the resources I've found seem to either be outdated, or unsuited to my needs. The development tool I'm using allows me to plug in HTML5 code, but I need to be able to plug in a video that will run without user input. It should also be noted that these video's must be hosted online somewhere (ie, It cant have the video load from inside the app).

Any Help you could give me on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify OS or device or browser. It's been a long time and you probably don't care anymore but if anyone else comes past this, my answer.

Try placing "playsinline" inside the video tag.

Eg. `<video playsinline> </video>`

I can confirm this works in iOS 10.